# Search operators not working correctly

Tags: bug, search

I like to search for questions that aren't closed, that has at least one answer but which doesn't have an accepted or upvoted answer, so that I can surface hidden gems that deserve votes.

```
closed:no answers:1 isanswered:0
```

However, the last time I performed [this search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A1+isanswered%3A0+), one of the questions returned was this one:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/63091/gmail-marks-legitimate-mail-as-spam

This question is not only closed, but its only answer has been deleted and shouldn't be counted anyway. That's not what I want.

I've been using this same search for well over a year and never had anything else happen like that.

So...

- am I crazy and just never noticed? If so, what's the search I *really* want?
- have the actions of one or more search operators changed recently?
- is there a bug in one or more of the search operators, or specifically with this combo?

---

This seems to still be in play. Searching for [`[google-checkout] closed:0`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-checkout%5D+closed%3A0) returns [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/changing-shipping-options-using-the-google-checkout-shopping-cart), which, if you look, has been closed since December, 2015. A search on [`[google-checkout] closed:1`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-checkout%5D+closed%3A1) returns four questions (all closed today).

What's the deal?

Comment: I'm thinking this will get more (and the right) eyes on it at MSE, but I will leave it up to you if you want to go that route.

Comment: Supposedly the Stack Exchange team monitors bugs and feature requests on all of the per-site metas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to have been fixed as a result of the [work being done on Elastic Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300917/21960), which includes re-indexing.