# Search index is way out of date

Tags: support, bug, search

I think there's something wrong with this site's search reindexing job.

For instance, a search for [[google-chrome] closed:0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-chrome%5D+closed%3A0) (sorted by relevance) lists [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59803/backing-up-google-drive-on-a-different-storage-device-on-chrome-os) having been asked in April, 2014 and with only the [google-chrome](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) tag. However, if you visit the question, it was modified in March, 2017, and doesn't even *have* the [google-chrome](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) tag on it.

This is probably the root cause of the [bug reported in this question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4069/354). Could, maybe, someone on the development team take a look?

Comment: Yes, I saw on the Uber Meta they had redone search indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would appear to have been fixed as a result of the [work being done on Elastic Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300917/21960), which includes re-indexing.